# Apache Hadoop Common FAILURE while installing Hadoop

Tags: maven, hadoop

I'm got an error while installing Hadoop(2.6.5).
I could not able to figure out and solve this problem.
Why does this error occur?
How do I fix this error?

> ### [INFO]
>
> [INFO] Reactor Summary:
>
> [INFO]
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [ 
>   5.475 s]
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [ 
>   2.819 s]
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [ 
>   7.908 s]
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [ 
>   0.513 s]
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [ 
>   3.950 s]
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [ 
>   9.448 s]
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [ 
>   8.859 s]
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [
>   10.867 s]
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [
>   11.076 s]
>
> **[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... FAILURE [28.798 s]**   << this is the problem
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal .............. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn ........................................ SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-api .................................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-common ................................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server ................................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-common .......................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager ..................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy ....................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice ....... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager ................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-tests ........................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-client ................................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications ........................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell .......... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher ..... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-site ................................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-registry ............................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-yarn-project ................................ SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client ............................ SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-core ....................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-common ..................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle .................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-app ........................ SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs ......................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient .................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins ................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples ................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce ................................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming .................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy ..................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ................................ SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix .............................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ............................ SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Ant Tasks ............................ SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras ............................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ................................ SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support .................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Amazon Web Services support .......... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Client ............................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ......................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist ........................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ................................ SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [INFO] Total time: 01:37 min
>
> [INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-21T15:34:48+00:00
>
> [INFO] Final Memory: 55M/151M
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project
>   hadoop-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 2
>
> [ERROR] around Ant part ...... @ 7:125 in
>   /root/hadoop-2.6.4-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml
>
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with
>   the command
>
> [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :hadoop-common

Comment: What OS are you building on and do you have all the prerequisites installed?  https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/BUILDING.txt

Comment: This isn't "installing" Hadoop. It's building the source code, which isn't required to just run it

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I uploaded a new post, can you check it for me?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425701/apache-hadoop-common-failure-while-building-hadoop

Comment: @guest1 what OS you are try building the source code?

Comment: @BrunoWego The OS is raspbian.