# Apache Hadoop Common FAILURE while building Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Hello i just uploaded the same question yesterday, but my explanation was poor.

> [Apache Hadoop Common FAILURE while installing Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416568/apache-hadoop-common-failure-while-installing-hadoop)

< it's a my previous post.

i'm want to install Hadoop in a raspberry pi base on the raspbian OS.

> http://data.andyburgin.co.uk/post/157450047463/running-hue-on-a-raspberry-pi-hadoop-cluster

< i refer to this site.

**Compile Hadoop

```
We now need to compile the Hadoop binaries, download and unpack the Hadoop 2.6.4 source, tweak pom.xml so it bypasses the documentation generation as this fails on the Pi, apply the HADOOP-9320 patch and build the binary.
cd
apt-get install oracle-java8-jdk
wget http://apache.mirror.anlx.net/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.6.4/hadoop-2.6.4-src.tar.gz
tar -zxvf hadoop-2.6.4-src.tar.gz
vi hadoop-2.6.4-src/pom.xml
Disable the problem step in by adding the following to <properties>…</properties>
    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
Next apply the HADOOP-9320 patch
cd hadoop-2.6.4-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src
wget https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12570212/HADOOP-9320.patch
patch < HADOOP-9320.patch
cd ~/hadoop-2.6.4-src/
Next install a whole bunch of build tools and libraries:
apt-get install maven build-essential autoconf automake libtool cmake zlib1g-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libfuse-dev libsnappy-dev libsnappy-java libbz2-dev**
<< i've finished this line.

but the error occurred at the next stage >  **sudo mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar**
```

how do i fix this error? please help. thank you :)

Comment: You can install using [builded source](https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.9.2/hadoop-2.9.2.tar.gz).

Comment: Perhaps [this help you](https://github.com/brunowego/cookbooks/blob/master/Apache%20Hadoop/Installation.md).

Comment: Sorry for checking late! Thanks for your help :)